# Getting the __unicode__ to appear in the search fields in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to search based on class's `__unicode__` . Hence i need to class's `__unicode__` to appear in the search fields.

I tried this:

```
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['__unicode__',]
```

But when i search based on the **unicode**, i am get this error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword '' into field.
```

How do i solve this error? Need some guidance...

The `__unicode__` method looks like this:

```
 def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username + ' ' + self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname + ' ' + self.email
```

Comment: as @DanielRoseman said you can't do that, what you can do is look into Django's Q class to combine a search on a collection of ModelFields, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Search is done at the database level, and `__unicode__` is not a database field.

Answer (score 0):

What does your model's `__unicode__` method do?

Most likely, it combines a few hand-picked model fields into a string for display purposes. The reasonable thing to do in that situation is to put those same fields into `search_fields`, and let the database search on those fields instead.